# Unity prefab from multiple sprites

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites

I am making a prefab of a simple building by combining sprites. As you can see in the Hierarchy view, this simple building is composed of very many gameobjects which I created via dragging sprites into the scene/Hierarchy and then manually editing their coordinate positions. [image: Building with many game objects]

Is there a simpler way of doing this? I feel that the process of creating this building consumed too much time I could spend on other aspects of development. If this is the only way, then in what ways could I optimize my workflow?

Comment: Why didn't you just create a grid and use tilemaps??

Comment: I have a grid with a tilemap, but I need to make a prefab

Comment: Even if you're not using tiles, you should still create a grid and put all of the gameObjects inside that grid. That way, they snap to position, rather than you having to manually adjust their transform values.

Comment: You're welcome, but I think you can still use tilemaps. Create a new tilemap inside your grid, call it 'Building', recreate the building using tiles, then create a prefab out of that tilemap.

Comment: Excellent. I was hoping there'd be a solution like that. I'll accept that as the answer, if it is posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of the grid that you already have, create a new tilemap and call it 'Building'. Then create the building using tiles, and when you're done, just make a prefab out of that tilemap.

Answer (score 1):

You could have used texture tiling from a mesh renderer to duplicate pieces automatically. [3D components can be used for 2D objects to add more complex functionality](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/2d-scrolling-backgrounds?playlist=17093).Drag and drop the sprite you want to duplicate as a material in the parent game object and change the shader to 'unlit texture.' You can play with the offset and tiling settings. Make sure the wrap mode in your import settings is set to 'repeat.'

You could have done this even faster by using gimp for the editing. Gimp has built in functions and plugins that handle this use case well. Filters > Map > Tile is one.